What stops the Devil from extensively manipulating Christians from a Biblical perspective?
Research shows that human beings can be pretty easily manipulated. This manipulation can be effectively done by ordinary humans with no special powers. Why, then, is Devil (who is generally believed to be a better manipulator than an average human) so impotent at his evil deeds? Why doesn't he manipulate humans into doing something sinful, or just something that will lead towards sin later down the line? Is there a Biblical answer to these questions?

Hello, and welcome to the site! There is quite some variation in Christian beliefs so I've written a somewhat generic answer. Is there a specific Christian viewpoint you are looking for?

Nope, that's pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

"Why doesn't he manipulate humans into doing something sinful, or just something that will lead towards sin later down the line?" — What is the basis of your assumption that this doesn't happen?

If such thing is within his power, then I'd expect to see sin much more often. It is not a rare occasion now, but I'd expect it to be completely total in almost every action if there was a super powerful divine manipulator behind it.

Like your other question on Life Extension.  asking from a "Biblical Perspective" is open to interpretation - please read this meta post https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians for why

you can ask about a "Biblical Basis" if you know or suspect that some particular denomination believes that something does stop the Devil.  For instance, I don't think the Catholic Church teaches that the Devil can directly manipulate a person without their consent.  I don't know about other faith traditions.  Asking "What is the Biblical Basis" for this belief, makes a good, supported question

God is more powerful; He limits what the adversary is able to do. In a number of places, Scripture explains that God allows temptation. The obvious corollary is that the tempter is limited to what God allows.

That said, all humans are sinful, and many reject God, so the assertion that Satan "isn't doing well" doesn't seem merited.

You're asking for logic, so approach logically. The original Hebrew word for "satan" or "devil" simply means "accuser". That's all there's to it. Accusation is when one claims that there's any other source of truth than greater good. Whenever you accuse, you are dissatisfied with the Creator and its creation. And ultimately, yourself. Accusation is a stalemate of critical thinking. Unattended it leads to rejection of life. It's generally believed that normally faith prevails and one overcomes all difficulties, and connects to the best, because why settle for less. That's why.

1 John 5:19  The whole world lies in the power of the wicked one (wickedness).  If the devil can get a person to disbelieve that God exists and to live an apparently moral life according to his own standard or to believe in a false god and live according to some man made religion that is a victory for him.  The idea that sin must be blatant, and horrible, and easily perceived is a false one (Romans 2:14-15).

Satan does seek to manipulate people, and God offers strength against it:

31 And the Lord said, Simon, Simon, behold, Satan hath desired to have
you, that he may sift you as wheat:
32 But I have prayed for thee, that thy faith fail not: and when thou
art converted, strengthen thy brethren. (Luke 22:31-32)

God offers direction as well:

Howbeit when he, the Spirit of truth, is come, he will guide you into
all truth (John 16:13a)

God is more powerful than Satan:

For this purpose the Son of God was manifested, that he might destroy
the works of the devil. (1 John 3:8b)

God sets limits:

There hath no temptation taken you but such as is common to man: but God is faithful, who will not suffer you to be tempted above that ye are able; but will with the temptation also make a way to escape, that ye may be able to bear it. (1 Cor 10:13)

People can choose which voice to listen to and which direction to follow (see Joshua 24:15), but Christians believe that God set up a system that works, wherein it is possible to be led into all truth.
(it is certainly also possible for someone to resist God's influence and be blinded by Satan--see 2 Cor 4:4)

I think you really should include 1 Corinthians 10:13, the verse where God will not allow you to be tempted beyond your ability.

@Wyrsa good call! Citation added
